# LINQ's OrderBy behaves different in Visual Studio's Immediate window than within the code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core

i see diffrent results when using LINQ's `OrderBy` function on a list in .NET and Visual Studio's Immediate window:

**Info**

- Visual Studio 2022 Enterprise 17.4.4
- .NET 6 Console project

**Code**

```cs
var l = new List<string>() {
            "a-test.de",
            "a.de"
        };


Console.WriteLine(l.OrderBy(e => e).ToList().First());
```

**Result when running the programm**

Output is `"a-test.de"`

**Result when using the immediate window**

If i set a debugger after the console output and i run `l.OrderBy(e => e).ToList().First()` within the immediate window the output is `"a.de"`

[image]

**The question**

What am i missing? :)

Thank you very much

Comment: @wenbingeng-MSFT i don't now exactly what you asking for - the question is asked in the initial post :)

Comment: This is normal, as this is a feature that even windows itself comes with. Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/immediate-window?view=vs-2022

Answer (score 2):

I suppose it depends on your current culture

Try to specify comparer for [OrderBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=net-7.0#system-linq-enumerable-orderby-2(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-func((-0-1))-system-collections-generic-icomparer((-1))))

```
 var l = new List<string>() {
            "a-test.de",
            "a.de"
        };


Console.WriteLine(l.OrderBy(e => e, StringComparer.Ordinal).ToList().First());
```

It should achieve the same behavior

Comment: Well, it does solve the issue, but doesn't explain. The culture should be the same between  execution and evalution at immediate window, the context should be the same. It's strange that they produce different results

Comment: Interestingly, the result of the immediate window behaves the same as in a Powershell instance `@("a-test.de", "a.de") | sort | select -first 1` returns also `"a.de"`